# Csv pandas reader delimiter does not work

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a csv file delimited by a comma.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/data_notebook-1_crime.csv', sep= ',')
print(df.head)
```

Unfortunately if I print the results all values are in the first column as seen in the picture

[Header of Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa7hI.jpg)

Csv file: https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/api/views/icn6-v9z3/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD

Comment: can you paste the source here and format as code? Check for quotes inside the file

Comment: Could you share the first 20 lines of your dataframe in order for us to try a helpful solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the results from 3.8.6

```
Python 3.8.6 (default, Oct 28 2020, 18:56:32) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.31.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/Crime.csv',sep=',')
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (1,18) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
>>> df
        Incident ID Offence Code  CR Number    Dispatch Date / Time NIBRS Code  Victims  ...         Start_Date_Time           End_Date_Time   Latitude  Longitude Police District Number             Location
0         201223224         2303  190002520  01/16/2019 03:51:46 PM        23C        1  ...  01/16/2019 03:51:00 PM                     NaN  39.037367 -77.051662                     4D  (39.0374, -77.0517)
1         201224613         2006  190004310  01/27/2019 06:05:56 PM        200        1  ...  01/27/2019 06:05:00 PM                     NaN  39.146531 -77.184940                     6D  (39.1465, -77.1849)
2         201267200         1103  190057412  11/28/2019 06:08:02 AM        11A        1  ...  11/28/2019 06:08:00 AM                     NaN  39.034255 -77.049163                     4D  (39.0343, -77.0492)
3         201230900         1399  190011960  03/15/2019 10:53:22 AM        13B        2  ...  03/15/2019 10:50:00 AM  03/15/2019 10:55:00 AM  39.141812 -77.224489                     6D  (39.1418, -77.2245)
4         201265312         1399  190055150  11/15/2019 03:31:20 PM        13B        1  ...  11/15/2019 03:20:00 PM                     NaN  39.159339 -77.198516                     6D  (39.1593, -77.1985)
...             ...          ...        ...                     ...        ...      ...  ...                     ...                     ...        ...        ...                    ...                  ...
225676    201248696         4104  190034187  07/18/2019 06:48:53 PM        90G        1  ...  07/18/2019 06:48:00 PM                     NaN  39.075179 -77.112958                     1D   (39.0752, -77.113)
225677    201250353         2902  190036349  07/30/2019 04:39:04 PM        290        1  ...  07/11/2019 03:00:00 PM  07/11/2019 11:13:00 PM  39.119276 -77.156921                     1D  (39.1193, -77.1569)
225678    201250255         2305  190035784  07/27/2019 01:20:11 PM        23F        1  ...  07/19/2019 09:30:00 AM  07/27/2019 11:30:00 AM  39.030905 -77.057040                     4D   (39.0309, -77.057)
225679    201243750         2203  190028212  06/13/2019 10:33:01 AM        220        1  ...  06/13/2019 10:33:00 AM  06/13/2019 11:30:00 AM  38.990216 -77.024017                     3D   (38.9902, -77.024)
225680    201244611         2309  190029400  06/19/2019 08:22:39 PM        23H        1  ...  04/19/2019 12:00:00 PM  06/19/2019 08:22:00 PM  39.098924 -76.920850                     3D  (39.0989, -76.9208)

[225681 rows x 30 columns]
>>>
```

The warning on the dtype can be overcome with an argument like

```
dtype={"user_id": int, "username": "string"}
```

I would check your version of python and pandas.

Comment: Thanks everything worked now there was a problem with the saved csv-file. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `df.head()` instead `df.head` here.

Output `df.head`:

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of         Incident ID Offence Code  CR Number    Dispatch Date / Time  ...   Latitude  Longitude Police District Number             Location
0         201087097         5707   16033232                     NaN  ...  39.078911 -77.080827                     4D  (39.0789, -77.0808)
1         201215730         5311  180058531  11/22/2018 04:58:01 AM  ...  38.973022 -76.996799                     8D   (38.973, -76.9968)
2         201229073         3562  190009928  03/03/2019 04:59:49 AM  ...  38.956840 -77.111362                     2D  (38.9568, -77.1114)
3         201233523         1114  190015440  04/03/2019 11:53:15 AM  ...  39.020392 -77.012776                     3D  (39.0204, -77.0128)
4         201087102         3562   16033238                     NaN  ...  38.991701 -77.024096                     3D  (38.9917, -77.0241)

[225681 rows x 30 columns]
```

Output `df.head()`:

```
   Incident ID Offence Code  CR Number    Dispatch Date / Time  ...   Latitude  Longitude Police District Number             Location
0    201087097         5707   16033232                     NaN  ...  39.078911 -77.080827                     4D  (39.0789, -77.0808)
1    201215730         5311  180058531  11/22/2018 04:58:01 AM  ...  38.973022 -76.996799                     8D   (38.973, -76.9968)
2    201229073         3562  190009928  03/03/2019 04:59:49 AM  ...  38.956840 -77.111362                     2D  (38.9568, -77.1114)
3    201233523         1114  190015440  04/03/2019 11:53:15 AM  ...  39.020392 -77.012776                     3D  (39.0204, -77.0128)
4    201087102         3562   16033238                     NaN  ...  38.991701 -77.024096                     3D  (38.9917, -77.0241)

[5 rows x 30 columns]
```

To check if all columns were set correctly, we can use the `info` function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./Crime.csv", sep=",")

print(df.info())
```

We can see that all columns are set as intended:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 225681 entries, 0 to 225680
Data columns (total 30 columns):
 #   Column                  Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------                  --------------   -----  
 0   Incident ID             225681 non-null  int64  
 1   Offence Code            225681 non-null  object 
 2   CR Number               225681 non-null  int64  
 3   Dispatch Date / Time    157045 non-null  object 
 4   NIBRS Code              225681 non-null  object 
 5   Victims                 225681 non-null  int64  
 6   Crime Name1             225540 non-null  object 
 7   Crime Name2             225540 non-null  object 
 8   Crime Name3             225540 non-null  object 
 9   Police District Name    225681 non-null  object 
 10  Block Address           205179 non-null  object 
 11  City                    224624 non-null  object 
 12  State                   225681 non-null  object 
 13  Zip Code                222494 non-null  float64
 14  Agency                  225681 non-null  object 
 15  Place                   225681 non-null  object 
 16  Sector                  225622 non-null  object 
 17  Beat                    225622 non-null  object 
 18  PRA                     225640 non-null  object 
 19  Address Number          205253 non-null  float64
 20  Street Prefix           9949 non-null    object 
 21  Street Name             225681 non-null  object 
 22  Street Suffix           4243 non-null    object 
 23  Street Type             225367 non-null  object 
 24  Start_Date_Time         225681 non-null  object 
 25  End_Date_Time           109034 non-null  object 
 26  Latitude                225681 non-null  float64
 27  Longitude               225681 non-null  float64
 28  Police District Number  225681 non-null  object 
 29  Location                225681 non-null  object 
dtypes: float64(4), int64(3), object(23)
memory usage: 51.7+ MB
```

So it seems that you are using some different data or doing something else than your question states.

Comment: Yes but I still would have the problem that I get all the values in columns one

Comment: That's just wrong. I added a sample showing that all columns are set as intended with the data you linked.